# How to create oauth_signature for OAuth-based authentication using Magento 2.0 REST API

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, oauth, magento-2.0

How do I create an **oauth_signature** for OAuth-based authentication in Magento 2.0 REST API requests?

Assuming I use PHP's hash_hmac:

```
hash_hmac ( 'sha1' , $string , 'Integrations-Consumer-Secret' );
```

I'm not sure what $string should contain

Comment: If you get answer, please reply back

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use Access token as [bearer token](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-token.html) in Authorization header (OAuth 2.0 style), instead of creating signature (OAuth 1.0a style).

Header name: `Authorization`, Header value: `Bearer access_token_goes_here`

If you still want to sign request in 1.0a style, then consider using some library, e.g. PHP [OAuth extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.oauth.php)

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something but the docs seem to suggest I need to build a far more complex Authorization header: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-oauth.html#oauth-handshake

Comment: Try token-based one http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-token.html

The one you mentioned is for systems like ERP, which have multiple users behind them.

@GuyC What is your integration use case?

Comment: We're integrating a 3rd Party Web Application, the token based method seemed to target mobile app's? I wanted to have users log into Magento via another site, and then let the other site connect via the OAuth API to grab the required Magento data for that user's session.

Comment: Unfortunately such case is not supported. There is no endpoint on Magento side to which you may redirect users for authorizing with Magento credentials (for OAuth tokens generation). As a workaround, you may ask user to enter their Magneto credentials somewhere on your side and use these credentials to obtain access token for their account (but users should trust your application enough in this case).

Comment: Ok, so instead we use token authentication and pass the users username & password to magento with the method you detailed above? Thank you for your help with this

Comment: If token-based authentication satisfies your security requirements (users will enter their Magento credentials on your site), then this will work.